# I am having trouble with Java in Eclipse with finding a file that is clearly there

Tags: java, eclipse

I can't seem to find the problem, debugging isn't working. But basically, I can clearly see that the file is in Eclipse. The file is there, but the program won't read it. What do I do?

This is the code to pull the file:

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("studentData.txt"));
```

It won't pull the file though

Comment: Print the exception.  It is probably not in the path you are expecting it to be in.

Comment: If you just use the filename to read the file then file should be present in the project base dir.

Comment: define "file is here" and "here"

Comment: `Path` is most certainly the issue. Use `new File("whereareyou.txt")` and it will show you, via a search for that file, the underlying path you are attempting to use, which is most likely at the root of the eclipse project. I use NetBeans so not 100% about eclipse behavoir.

Answer (score 1):

The exception tells you the problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
try 
{ 
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(""));  
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //do something with e, or handle this case
    }
}
```

Or you can use-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
 Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("path"));  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
this.class.getResourceAsStream(path);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Try to put in the FileReader constructor the full path of your file or at least the path in the workspace :)

Answer (score 0):

FileReader class receive the path of file with its name like C:\studentData.txt. I assume you're reading a file from the same directory where you have this java class.
if this then try this code:

```
String currDirectoryPath = System.getProperty("user.dir"); // return current path
String path = currDirectoryPath+File.separator +"studentData.txt";
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(path));
```

hope it helps.